# CSS file not located in live XAMPP Server

Tags: php, html, css, xampp, href

My **project's structure** looks like this so far:

[image: project structure]

I tried to link my **CSS file** by accessing my projects path, then /css, then /style.css which appears to be correct when opening the .html file ***locally*** on a browser.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">`

After opening up my **Apache** server and the **dev console**, this specific error occurs that talks about my .css file.

`GET http://localhost/hospitalphp/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

It seems weird to me since the reference works just fine in normal browsers but doesn't work in my server.

FOR MORE INFO:

I included my .html in the **index.php** file

[image: .html include]

Error message in live server:

[image: No css error]

Opening just the .html file:

[image: css works]

If you think I didn't include something important to my problem, make sure to comment! I am still trying to figure this out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your syntax is incorrect:

```
 include("assets\pages\index.html")
```

should be

```
 include("assets/pages/index.html")
```

Secondly, based on the directory structure in the screenshot, you should use:

```
 include("pages/index.html")
```

or even better (see blow links):

```
 require("pages/index.html")
```

I am curious as to why you are including your index.html in your index.php like that?

See [PHP, How to set include path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780236/php-how-to-set-include-path) if you intend to include many files like that.

Additionally, your question is confusing as the screenshot does not include a `hospitalphp` directory as indicated in the error message you posted:

GET http://localhost/**hospitalphp**/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I don't know if it's a weird way of including it or not, since I have just started getting into PHP. Judging from your comment I am pretty sure there's a better way to do this. How can I do it? Thanks for your input!

Comment: <?php
include("config.php");
?>
...
<h1>HTML here</h1>
...

Comment: My original question wasn't solved even with `include("assets/page/index.html")`, no change happened.