# understanding glob() function

Tags: php, include, glob

I wanted to include some files from a directory , so my code had :

```
foreach (glob("inc/*.php") as $filename)
{
    include $filename;
}
```

This syntax is referenced almost in all related items on the net ( [example question on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599670/how-to-include-all-php-files-from-a-directory) )

But .. there were no results.

So I tried

```
 foreach (glob(".inc/*.php") as $filename)
    {
        include $filename ;
    }
```

and then :

```
foreach (glob("/inc/*.php") as $filename)
    {
        include $filename;
    }
```

And finally I added `dirname(__FILE__)` :

```
 foreach ( glob( dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/*.php' ) as $filename) {
    include( $filename );
}
```

Which worked .

So everything is ok now ( no need to panic ) , but for the sake of understanding , I have some issues I want to clarify :

1 . Why did `glob()` worked for me only when I added `dirname(__FILE__)` ?

2 . Is there a difference in syntax between *NIX and windows servers ?

3 . It is actually the first time I noticed the syntax `include $filename` - where are the parenthesis ? why they are not needed in this context?

Comment: 1. Wrong current directory, 2. not in this case, 3. because it's a language construct, not a function.

Comment: Thanks , But why was it wrong current directory ? The file for my understanding was in the right place ( same dir as the `inc` subdir.. )

Comment: Paths are not relative to the current script, but to the current working directory.

Comment: @mario ok :-) that would explain a lot :-) Are you sure you do not want to add as answer ?