# cannot include directory in public_html

Tags: php

I need to include a library, which I have stored directly in public_html.

I can't seem to include it with this in the file abc.php which is also stored directly under public_html...

```
 include_once '../sdk-core-php-master';
```

The error keeps telling me

```
 PHP Warning:  include_once(../sdk-core-php-master): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/abc/domains/abc.com/public_html/abc.php
```

I tried many variations like adding more ../ in front but to no luck. Get same error.
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: wich file you can include? or sdk-core-php-master is a file?

Answer (score 1):

ATT:

you don't add the extension:

```
include_once(../sdk-core-php-master):
```

it should be: `include_once('../sdk-core-php-master.php'):`

you can use magic constant to handle it.
see reference here: [**PHP Magic Constant**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

to see your directory, just echo as follows:

```
dirname(__FILE__);
```

so, write your including file, as follows:

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/sdk-core-php-master');
```

If it still not working, you can add commentary lines, as follows (and this should work):

e.g.

```
<?php
##########-------------start:anticrash--------------##########
##############################################################
##########--------------end:anticrash---------------##########
 include_once '../sdk-core-php-master';
//.............
//other codes
?>
```

Comment: `__DIR__` is a shorter equivalent

Comment: i have the same issue with this, but I really like using anticrash and it works successfully. is there anything a bug so that commentary in php could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question right, you're trying to use a php library, which means you have to add the .php extension like:

```
include_once '../sdk-core-php-master.php';
```

Edit: If you're trying to include multiple files from one folder, take a look at this question: [How to include() all PHP files from a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599670/how-to-include-all-php-files-from-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the address of files from the root drive. In variable $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] holds the address of the site root. Added to this address of files from the **root of the site**.
For example:

> `include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/some-folder/sdk-core-php-master.php");`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answer. I fixed it eventually. Apparently, my included path was set incorrectly. So I reset it to

```
set_include_path('http://www.example.com/');
```

and then include every file in the folder...it works now.

```
foreach (glob('sdk-core-php-master/*') as $filename)
{
    include_once $filename;
}
```