# PHP: How to include all files from all subdirectories from a directory

Tags: php, file, directory, subdirectory

I want to include many PHP files from many subdirectories. But it will be very annoying if I have to use include for each subdirectory.

For example:

```php
include "./subdir1/*.php";
include "./subdir2/*.php";
include "./subdir3/*.php";
```

So, is there a way to include all files from all subdirectories from a directory just with one `include` statement?

Comment: I'm sure you know how to configure your include path using php.ini.  If you're writing an application ... and the application needs a million includes throughout your PHP code ... then there's probably something fundamentally wrong with your application's design :(

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599670/how-to-include-all-php-files-from-a-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599670/how-to-include-all-php-files-from-a-directory)

Comment: Which method you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

use php glob function. Example code below

```
foreach (glob(document_root.'/class/*.php') as $filename) {
    require_once($filename);
}
```